# IntelliJ Idea, how to remove java file directory from Console?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When you run a file, it opens the console window and all the way on top it has the directory of where the file is. This is pretty irritating because now, to separate other lines from mixing with the directory, I have to use "\n" on before any System.out.println() commands can be initiated.

"C:\Program FIles..." I want to get rid of that.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question and maybe add a screenshot of your exact problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is presently no way to disable this.

It does show useful information which shows which jvm is being used and which parameters are used to configure it, so it does "annotate" your program log to some extent. You'll also get a line stating the exit code when your program terminates.

There is an option to be able to write the console log to a file, I'm not sure if it shows the jvm version and exit code or not, perhaps you can try it and see if it is be useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try Settings->Editor->General->Console, in the "Fold console lines that contain:", add a substring of the line you want folded e.g. "C:\Program Files